# jQuery Select2 Plugin using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-select2

I am using the Select2 plugin with Ajax to connect to my employee database. It allows to set up a meeting and choose all of the employees you want to invite.

This is what the code looks like:

```
$("#requiredAttendees").select2({
            multiple: true,
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            placeholder: "Search for employee",
            tokenSeparators: [" "],
            ajax: { 
                url: "jsonUser.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (term) {
                    return {
                        term: term, // search term
                    };
                },
                results: function (data) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                    return {results: data};
                }
            },
        });
```

This is the jSON response when I have typed my last name in the field:

`[{"id":"12345","text":"Hussey, Sam},{"id":"67890","text":"Hussey, Carl"}]`

My issue is, when narrowing down the search results, I am trying to narrow it down even more by searching for the first name as well. So I would type `Hussey, c` and expect it to only show my result.

However, as soon as I type a comma, I get no results found.

I assume the code is treating anything with a comma as a new result but i cant be certain.

This is my JSON output:

```
//Define the output
$firstName  = (string) $emp->FirstName;
$lastName   = (string) $emp->LastName;
$empID      = (string) $emp->EmpID;
$email      = (string) $emp->email;

//Add the resykts to an array
$users[] = array(
    'id' => $empID,
    'text' => $lastName . ', ' . $firstName,
);

}

//Set the content type to JSON  for jquery to understand
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//Print the response to the page
print json_encode($users);
```

Any ideas of what would cause this?

EDIT:

This is the part where I send the query:

```
//Define some variables
$query    = $_GET['term'];
$users    = array();

//Prevent running if less than 3 char have bene submitted
if (strlen($query) < 3) {
    die();
}

//Create a new database connection
$objDB = new DB;
$xml   = $objDB->setStoredProc('focusGetEmp')->setParam("LastName", $query)->execStoredProc()->parseXML();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now resolved. The search term is just fetching the results directly from the query so I had to adjust that to fix it.

Before

```
WHERE    LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%'
```

After

```
WHERE    A.[LastName] + ', ' + A.[FirstName] LIKE '%' + @term + '%'
```